# Is there an alternative to downloads_path_provider for flutter?

Tags: flutter

The package "downloads_path_provider"  is deprecated so are there any new alternatives? I want my app to download a pdf to my device and access it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what about `android_external_storage: ^0.1.0` you can acces root folder and access download folder .with enable the userpermissioin

Comment: you can try flutter_downloader: ^1.7.2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.